# simple fading image swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slideshow

I'm having trouble finding a simple jquery image swap. Most the examples I've found are more complex than I need, and do things I don't want.

Objective: I have 5 images I want to fade in, slide in, or etc. I would love to fade/dissolve from one image to the next, but slide would be fine too. When the page 1st loads, I want the 1st image to show for 4 seconds...then fade to the next image, 4 seconds, then the next, etc. Infinite loop.

Currently my code is a simple image swap, not very elegant:

```
document.getElementById("imgMain").src = "images/yurt/sleigh.png";
```

What's the best and simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Pick a plugin. Any plugin. It doesn't matter which one. There are plenty to pick from. Now use it, and move on to solving problems which are actually interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Working example on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/2kkHH/)

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="fadein">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8359/8450229021_9d660578b4_n.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8510/8452880627_0e673b24d8_n.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8108/8456552856_a843b7a5e1_n.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8230/8457936603_f2c8f48691_n.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8329/8447290659_02c4765928_n.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fadein {
    position:relative;
    height:320px;
    width:320px;
}

.fadein img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                             .next('img')
                             .fadeIn()
                             .end()
                             .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 4000); // 4 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you, but the rotating images get shifted outside of their box when I try your code: http://www.zerogravpro.com/yurt/  I would be very grateful if you could take a quick look and tell me what I need to do to get the rotating images back inside the brown border. Thanks in advance. I like the fade effect, it's perfect.

Comment: Change left: 0; to left: 85px; and that will fix the positioning issue.