# Fading image into another slowly

Tags: jquery, photo, fade

This is the link: **[Simple-fading-image-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795007/simple-fading-image-swap)**

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this, however, I'm needing to slower the change of photos down. Is there some way I can easily change the transition speed (time it spends fading)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2kkHH/517/)

```
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(4000)
                             .next('img')
                             .fadeIn(10)
                             .end()
                             .appendTo('.fadein');
},4000 ); // 4 seconds
```

Comment: I like this better.  changing the time on the `fadeOut` has more of a 'fade' look.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2kkHH/512/)

```
setInterval(function () {
$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                         .next('img')
                         .fadeIn(3000)
                         .end()
                         .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 4000); // 4 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify time for fadeout

```
setInterval(function () {

        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(2000)// 2 seconds
                                 .next('img')
                                 .fadeIn(2000)
                                 .end()
                                 .appendTo('.fadein');
    }, 4000); // 4 seconds
```